# PHP unable to fetch the PDF file name in upload form

Tags: php

I can't upload PDF file using PHP. 
I have tried to get the name of file only for testing.

HTML:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" />
</form>
```

add.php:

```
<?php
  echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
?>
```

I got an error message:

> "Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www...".

but it worked for another files.

Please help me!

Comment: What's that file size? Does it exceed your PHP upload limit?

Comment: your code above seems to correct. if the filesize is greater than PHP upload size then it should throw the 'Invalid file' error? What size are the ones that fail?

Comment: Maximum default file upload size is 2MB. Check the pdf file size

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` is usually helpful. Errors can be looked up on the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, so its probably a problem to do with file size limits.

Add the following to `.htaccess` and see if it makes any difference.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

You could also make the changes in your `php.ini` like this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
```